# How to disable auto completion of Gnu Make version 3.82

Tags: gnu-make

After upgrading to Gnu Make of version 3.82, I found it supports target auto completion.

For some distribution, it might really helpful

However, with OpenWrt Linux Distribution, it might be troublesome since partial build is frequently like below

```
# make package/path/{clean,install} V=99
```

But we cannot do PATH auto completion because Gnu Make now is so "Smart" that it prints out the possible make targets for your selection instead of doing PATH auto completion

Comment: I got the solution that just remove bash_completion script of make can disable make auto completion

Answer (score 1):

> After upgrading to Gnu Make of version 3.82, I found it supports
>   target auto completion.

Unlikely that this makes sense. Completion on your shell is done by... your shell. So remove the completion support for Make from your shell configuration.